# Занят glassfish, не запускается приложение с IntelijIDEA

Tags: java, glassfish, localhost

Установил glassfish, localhost:4848 работает через браузер. 
А когда хочу запустить сервер через IDEA пишет Adress localhost:4848 is already in use. Где я его использую? Почему не дает работать? Возможно он уже запущен и не нужно мне его стартовать?

Comment: Попробуй сделать [так](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruG0SkRildo&t=58s) только вместо Tomcat настрой GlassFish. Укажи порт http://localhost:4848 в настройках. Server Domains указываешь где у тебя лежит GlassFish. Например: D:\glassfish-4.1.2-web\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1

Comment: @Владимир заработало. Вручную остановил glassfish (stop-domain), и с IDEA запустил. Заработало)